# Installation of boost on Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boost, compilation, installation

I need to compile program which uses headers from boost library. So I found two instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install boost-devel
```

What difference between **libboost-all-dev** and **boost-devel**? Maybe I must to install it with another one?

Comment: At least on my machine, ubuntu 12.04, there is no `boost-devel` in the standard repositories, while the `liboost-all-dev` exists.

Comment: Yes, you right, +1, I made aptitude search libboost-all-dev and it is exists, too. But what difference if both exist? They install same files?

Comment: I don't know the boost related specifics. To get more information about debian/ubuntu package, try `apt-cache show liboost-all-dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the boost related specifics.

To get more information about debian/ubuntu package, try:

`apt-cache show liboost-all-dev`